# how to detect short pause in a speech with noise?

Tags: matlab, audio, voice, detection

I would like to count the number of short pauses in a speech and know the duration of the pauses by loading the signal into Matlab but I am very new to Matlab.
Can anyone help and give me some ideas about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Voice Activity Detector(VAD) for detecting the pauses in speech and there location(and duration). if your input signal is not very noisy and noise is not varying much you can use a fixed threshold on the energy(calculated for short frames, ex-20 ms), so if energy is above that threshold you declare that frame as speech else pause. if input signal is very noisy(varying noise) you can use adaptive threshold and do the same,i.e. you can have short term(lasting for 10-12 frames) and long term energies(lasting 40-50frames) and long term energy can be used as threshold. once this classification is done for entire input signal you can get duration's of pauses in speech

Comment: Is VAD a function in matlab??? Sorry that I'm very new in this area

Comment: Hi, Matlab does not have inbuilt function VAD. but you can find implementations of VAD in matlab on web, or you can easily code it as I explained. you might find it useful - http://homepage.tudelft.nl/w5p50/pdffiles/VAD%20Techniques%20for%20Real-Time%20Speech%20Transmission%20on%20the%20Internet.pdf